# Where/how to host html/css website only accessible by link? (not referenced in google)

Tags: hosting

I've made up my first website and was wondering if there is a free way to host it and have it only accesible by a link that would be send by e-mail cause the content would't be referenced in google.

I'm helping a friend making a resume webpage for a school, and she don't want anybody to find her work and name associated to her work publicly.

I've looked into github, but i'm not sure it will provide it

Answer (score 0):

You could use heroku to host a simple website by using github

You just need a github account and heroku account

Then follow the following instructions for deployment

https://gist.github.com/jesperorb/86952f98ed7ea3d1fbfa54824b22eee0